# avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\\.\COM3": Access is denied

Tags: arduino

I get this error message when i try to upload code to my arduino. Does anyone know what is going on?

I have installed the proper drivers and it works fine. My port appears on the menu and it is the corresponent to the device.

bless

Answer (score 10):

Common error, here is the solution:

1 - Unplug the Arduino

2 - Upload code with no Arduino connected to PC

3 - Reconnect Arduino

4 - Upload code to the Arduino

Good luck!

Comment: And don't forget to close the Serial Monitor tab (between step 3 and 4) before you upload. This fixed my case on Arduino IDE v2.0.0 with Win10.

Comment: @Bart worked for me . In new Arduino IDE it was open by default

Comment: Saved me a lifetime, thank you

Answer (score 6):

If your using the arduino IDE 2.0 you must close the serial monitor tab if it’s open to upload a sketch. Otherwise you will get this error.

Comment: This fixed it for me version 2.1.1

Answer (score 3):

From terminal:

```sh
ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*
# or:
ls -l /dev/ttyACM*
```

Get the groupname from the result:

```sh
crw-rw---- 1 root uucp 188, 0  5 apr 23.01 ttyUSB0
# or:
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0  5 apr 23.01 ttyACM0
```

Add your username to the group:

```sh
usermod -a -G uucp username
# or:
usermod -a -G dialout username
```

Log out and in again for this change to take effect.

Source: https://playground.arduino.cc/Linux/All/#Permission

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Linux,
just set current user to belong to "dialout" group which is the one who members are allowed to access ports.

Run following:

```
sudo adduser yourUserName dialout
```

then relog to take effect

(Ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the USB-SERIAL CH340 driver: (on some cheaper ARDUINO clones)

1. Open Device Manager
2. Open Ports and click on the drop-down arrow to select your port.
3. Right-click and select "Properties"
4. Open the "Port Settings" tab.
5. Click on "advanced" to open a new window:
6. Un-tick "Use FIFO buffers (requires 16550 compatible UART)" and press "OK"

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGRv5.png)

Please let others know if this worked for you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the first thing to check is if all your Terminal Monitors are closed. The Serial Monitor of the **Arduino IDE** stays open even after restarting the software. **[Ctr-Shift-M]**

Answer (score 0):

USB may need CH340 driver.
Some Arduinos use the CH340 controller
Find and install the CH34X_Driver_V3.4_Windows.zip

Answer (score 0):

click right on this computer, go to management, device manager, com, find the port of Arduino, then go to tools and in port select the com

Answer (score 0):

I had the COM3 error too and this fixed it.

Open the Arduino application as Administrator
(Shift+Rightclick the app, 'Run as administrator').
I still had to upload without the Arduino connected, then connect and upload.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

1. If you are using **VS Code** with **Platform IO** and you ***spam*** Serial Monitor with ***many message too fast***, then when trying again to upload it will give you the above error. One way to solve it is to press the reset button on your board and immedietly after that to press upload in VS Code. Just don't spam the Serial Monitor too fast, when using VS Code with Platform IO and uploading while monitoring it.
2. If you are using **CLion** with **Platform IO** and you have **opened Serial Monitoring** via `pio device monitor` then you must **close it** and then upload, because it is **using the port**.

Answer (score 0):

be sure you are not using 2 ides connected to arduino like ARDUINO IDE and VS Code

Answer (score 0):

Another reason you can get this is if you have another application open that has the ability to use a COM port. For example, I do 3D printing, and if I have a 3D slicer like Ultimaker Cura open (which has the ability to communicate with your printer over serial) you get this error when trying to upload to an Arduino. You have to close that application before trying to upload to the Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

Check your connections if you have anything wired to the board with loose wires or clamps.

For anyone else that comes across this thread; I tried all these solutions and none of them had worked(would suggest trying those first if you haven't anyways as they're all good and logical solutions). What fixed it for me was that I noticed some bugginess with my servos randomly spinning, so I removed the wires from the pinouts and just had the Feather board alone connected to the Micro USB and was able to upload to it after that.